# Magento - setting url key in csv leads to 404 page

Tags: magento, url, csv, url-rewriting, product

I have a lot of products which need to be uploaded via csv in Magento. I have for example two attributes with values:

url_key

```
mypage
```

url_path

```
mypage.html
```

I have also tried the values the same, but when I upload them the products exist but always leads to an 404 error when trying to view their product page.

Is there somethig I'm missing out in the csv?

I'm using Magento 1.7

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does reindexing Catalog Url Rewrites after importing products help?

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to have a different URL that the Product Name?

EG Product ABC, Magento would make the URL key product-abc and URL Path product-abc.html by default.

If that is your goal then you can leave those 2 columns blank on your import and Magento will apply this rule. Also be sure to re-index after you import.

Answer (score 1):

Step 1 : Leave both column (url_key and url_path) empty and upload csv file

Step 2 : After succesful importing csv file, go to System -> Index Management :
Click on Select All and click on Submit.
It is very simple way. I tried and got result.